# RevTex 4-1 sample layout not functional in Lyx 2.2.3

Tags: lyx, miktex, texlive, lyx-layouts

I am trying to write a Physical Review Letter Style paper for the first time and I have always used Lyx instead of the raw Latex platform.

I tried to run the sample template that comes along with Lyx 2.2.3 and it seems to carry certain errors.

Could any kindly advice me what I can do about this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) May I suggest that you (1) go to the menu bar on the top, (2) expand `View`, (3) select `Source Pane`, (4) a new panel should pop up at the bottom titled `LaTeX Source`, (5) click the drop-down menu below the `Format` one and (6) choose `Complete Source`, (7) copy-paste the code shown in the main panel and edit in your post. We can help you only when we have enough information to debug.

Comment: It seems that as a new user I am prohibited from posting anything lengthy. Is there any other way that I can do this? By the way, the layout code comes with Lyx 2.2.3 by default in the revtex 4-1 package as a sample template. Could anyone look into it?